# How to sort the items then sort again by another condition using SQL

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL, and I want to sort a record or I want to group a record then sort it again by another condition like for example I have 6 items,

```
Names Group
Jack  G1
Dian  G2
Emily G2
Dean  G1
Teddy G2
Gabe  G1
```

So I want to sort this by group in alphabetized orby by name. Like,

```
Dean  G1
Gabe  G1
Jack  G1
Dian  G2
Emily G2
Teddy G2
```

So my problem is, how can I sort like this in MySQL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you want to order by one column first and then another? You can specify more than one column in the `ORDER BY` clause of a query - separate them by commas, and the first one will be the 'major' sort, then subsequent columns in the list will be sorted within that.

Answer (score 4):

```
Select * from MyTable order by MyGroup, MyNames
```

Answer (score 2):

Use two `ORDER BY`s.

```
ORDER BY Group ASC, Name ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select Names, Group 
from MyTable 
order by Group, Names
```

The order by list does not have to be in the same order as the select list columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Names, Group FROM 'table_name' ORDER BY Names DESC
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.