# Logic for Order By in SQL

Tags: sql-server

[image: 0]

I have a table which get result as left one of the photo.
However, I would like to get the result which order by:
1. first, compare the number in val field which group field's data must be 'total'. 
2. then, all data with same value at item field will get an order based on the order at condition 1
The right part of the photo is what I want the result is. How should I set the logic with ORDER BY? Thank you.

Comment: are you using `MySQL` or `SQL Server` ?

Comment: I am using mssql, but actually will using .net to generate the data and create excel

Comment: [duplicate] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171870/how-to-sort-the-items-then-sort-again-by-another-condition-using-sql

Comment: @Nidhi257, it is not really a duplicate, the criteria is not the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to join to a subquery which finds the totals for each item, and then to sort using that.

```
SELECT
    t1.item,
    t1.[group],
    t1.val
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT item, val AS total
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE [group] = 'total'
) t2
    ON t1.item = t2.item
ORDER BY
    t2.total DESC,
    t1.item,
    CASE WHEN t1.[group] = 'total' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    t1.[group];
```

Comment: might want to add to the `order by` , `t1.item`, after the t2.total incase there are tie for the total